# Bootstrap Standard Errors: should I divide the sampling standard deviation by $\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: regression, econometrics, nonparametric, bootstrap, standard-error

Suppose I am bootstrapping an OLS regression and want the standard error of the coefficient $\beta_1$. I estimate the following regression on 1000 resamples of the data (where $B$ indexes the bootstrap resample): $$y^B_i=\beta^B_0+\beta^B_1 x^B_i+\varepsilon^B_i$$

Is the standard error of $\beta_1$ given by  $sd(\beta^B_1)$ or $\frac{sd(\beta^B_1)}{\sqrt{n-1}}$ (where sd is the standard deviation)?

It seems correct to divide by $\sqrt{n-1}$ since that is how we usually define a standard error, but I have seen many references that instruct me to only take the standard deviation without dividing by $\sqrt{n-1}$.

Comment: I have the similar confusion, did you figure this out? It looks like when I divide sd by ${\sqrt{n-1}}$, then the confidence interval is very narrow compared with other CI methods.

Answer (score 2):

The standard error of the mean, with its $\sqrt{n-1}$ in the denominator, is a particular closed form of the standard error (SE), obtained exactly for the mean as a considered statistic. For any statistic, SE is defined as the *standard deviation* (SD) of its sampling distribution.

Thus, for the bootstrap, SE is the SD of statistic values obtained for bootstrap samples. In your case:

$$se=sd(\beta_1^B)$$ not the $$\frac{sd(\beta_1^B)}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$

Regarding the SE for mean, recall that $Var(aX) = a^2Var(X)$, where $a$ is some constant. Also, there is $Var(\sum_i X_i)$ = $\sum_i Var(X_i)$ for independent $X_i$. Therefore, we got:
$$Var(\bar X ) = Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n X_i) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i^nVar(X_i) =\frac{1}{n^2}n\sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$
where $\sigma$ is the variance of population from each $X_i$ is drawn.

How is this related to sampling distribution?
We can safely stop here and state that whenever there is a sampling of population by taking $n$ elements of it and statistic of interest  is the mean of those elements, the variance of that mean is given by $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$. So, the well-known form for the SE of mean is:

$$se_{mean}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$$ and with the Bessel's correction: $$se_{mean}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}}$$ .

But you also can find the following explanation. Let's denote vector of even sub-samples of the investigated population by $X_s = (X_{s_1}, X_{s_2}, ..., X_{s_k})$. If the population mean is estimated as total of all variates in $X_s$ divided by a total number of variates $n$, we got:
$$\bar X = \frac{1}{mk}\sum_{i,j}^{m,k} X_i,{s_j} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n} X^s_i$$

and reasoning is the same as for $Var(\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n X_i$). However, this is a shortcut and conceptually is different from considering the sampling distribution of the $\bar X$. Also, this approach will get nasty for $Var(\bar X)$ if we estimate $\bar X$ as the mean of means from sub-samples: $\bar X =\frac{1}{n} \sum^n_i \bar X_{s_i}$.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bradley & Efron if you want to estimate the standard error $se(\hat\theta)$ by the sample standard deviation of the $B$ replications you will take $$\hat{se}_{B} = \sum_{b=1}^{B}\left([\hat\theta^{\star}(b)-\hat\theta^{\star}(\cdot)]^2 / (B-1)\right)^{1/2}$$

where $\hat\theta^{\star}(\cdot) =\sum_{b=1}^{B}\hat\theta^{\star}(b)/B $

Doing so in R :

````
#Regression Data
#===============
n <- 27
x <- c(99, 152, 293, 155, 196, 53, 184, 171, 52, 376, 385, 402, 29, 76, 296, 151, 177, 209, 119, 188, 115, 88, 58, 49, 150, 107, 125)
y <- c(25.8, 20.5, 14.3, 23.2, 20.6, 31.1, 20.9, 20.9, 30.4, 16.3, 11.6, 11.8, 32.5, 32.0, 18.0, 24.1, 26.5, 25.8, 28.8, 22.0, 29.7, 28.9, 32.8, 32.5, 25.4, 31.7, 28.5)


#OLS Regression estimates
#========================
ones <- rep(1,n)
DM <- cbind(ones,x)
betas.OLS <- solve(t(DM)%*%DM)%*%t(DM)%*%y
betas.OLS

ehat.OLS <- y-DM%*%betas.OLS
ehat.OLS
sigma2.hat <- t(ehat.OLS)%*%ehat.OLS/(n-2)
sigma2.hat
sigma.hat <- sqrt(sigma2.hat)
sigma.hat
var.betas.OLS <- drop(sigma2.hat)*solve(t(DM)%*%DM)
var.betas.OLS
std.betas.OLS <- sqrt(diag(var.betas.OLS))
std.betas.OLS

betas.OLS
std.betas.OLS

#Nonparametric Bootstrap
#=======================
B<-10000
sample.betas<-NULL

for (i in 1:B) 
{
  Boot.residual.sample <- sample(ehat.OLS,size=n,replace=T)
  Y.sample <- DM%*%betas.OLS+Boot.residual.sample
  Boot.betas <- solve(t(DM)%*%DM)%*%t(DM)%*%Y.sample
  sample.betas <- cbind(sample.betas,Boot.betas)
}
sampling.mean <- apply(sample.betas,1,mean)
sampling.mean
sampling.var <- apply(sample.betas,1,var)
sampling.s.e <- sqrt(sampling.var)
sampling.s.e



#Parametric Bootstrap
#====================
B<-10000
sample.betas<-NULL

for (i in 1:B) 
{
  Boot.residual.sample <- rnorm(n,0,sigma.hat)
  Y.sample <- DM%*%betas.OLS+Boot.residual.sample
  Boot.betas <- solve(t(DM)%*%DM)%*%t(DM)%*%Y.sample
  sample.betas <- cbind(sample.betas,Boot.betas)
}
sampling.mean <- apply(sample.betas,1,mean)
sampling.mean
sampling.var <- apply(sample.betas,1,var)
sampling.s.e <- sqrt(sampling.var)
sampling.s.e
```
````

Comment: Is there an explicit answer to the question in the title lurking somewhere in this?

Comment: @BruceET read again my answer

Comment: Yes this is  the formula i was referring to. It is simply the std dev, not the std dev divided by $\sqrt{B-1}$. Any idea why we don't divide the std dev?

Comment: @lasoon because for any bootstrap sample $(x_{1}^{\star},x_{2}^{\star},\dots,x_{n}^{\star})$ you calculate the std of one sample.For $B$ total bootstrap samples you divide with $B-1$ as noted in the answer.If you don't divide with $B-1$ you have calculate only the std of one bootstrap sample

Comment: @Mr.Podilatis I don't follow. The definition of a std dev of a random variable $x$ is $$\sigma(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\sum_i^N (x_i-\overline{x})^2}{N}}$$ The standard error of the mean is then $$se(\overline{x})=\frac{\sigma(x)}{\sqrt{N}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sqrt{\frac{\sum_i^N (x_i-\overline{x})^2}{N}}$$ Notice that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ appears twice in thh standard error--once when computing the standard deviation and second when dividing the sd by $\sqrt{N}$ What you have written is simply the standard deviation of the bootstrapped distribution of means with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ appearing once.

Comment: My question is about the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ that multiplies the standard deviation $\sigma(x)$. Why does this additional $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ not appear in the bootstrap standard error formula but it appears in other contexts when estimating the standard error of the mean?